# aws-sdk-js transact operations not exposed to DocumentClient?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk-js

I'm developing some business administration software in JS and I find myself in need of ACID transactions with DynamoDb. Lucky of mine, AWS just released the transactGet and transactWrite APIs that covers just the right use case!

I'm using the AWS.DynamoDb.DocumentClient object to make my other calls and it seems like the transact operations are not exposed for me to use.

I hacked inside the aws-sdk code and found the interface exports like such ("aws-sdk": "^2.368.0", document_client.d.js, line 2076):

```
export interface TransactWriteItem {
  /**
   * A request to perform a check item operation.
   */
  ConditionCheck?: ConditionCheck;
  /**
   * A request to perform a PutItem operation.
   */
  Put?: Put;
  /**
   * A request to perform a DeleteItem operation.
   */
  Delete?: Delete;
  /**
   * A request to perform an UpdateItem operation.
   */
  Update?: Update;
}
```

However, whenever I try to call the client with this methods, I get back a Type error, namely:

```
TypeError: dynamoDb[action] is not a function
```

Locally, I can just hack the sdk and expose everything, but it is not accepted on my deployment environment.

How should I proceed?

Thank you very much!

**Edit**:
If it is worth anything, there is the code I'm using to do the calls:

*dynamo-lib.js:*

```
import AWS from "aws-sdk";

export function call(action, params) {
    const dynamoDb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
    return dynamoDb[action](params).promise();
}
```

*Lambda code:*

```
import * as dynamoDbLib from '../libs/dynamodb-lib';
import { success, failure } from '../libs/response-lib';

export default async function main(params, callback) {
    try {
        const result = await dynamoDbLib.call("transactWrite", params);
        callback(null, success(result));

    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        callback(null, failure({"status": "Internal server error"}));
    }
}
```

**Edit 2:**
Seems like the document client really does not export the method.

```
AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient = AWS.util.inherit({

  /**
   * @api private
   */
  operations: {
    batchGetItem: 'batchGet',
    batchWriteItem: 'batchWrite',
    putItem: 'put',
    getItem: 'get',
    deleteItem: 'delete',
    updateItem: 'update',
    scan: 'scan',
    query: 'query'
},
...
```

As mentioned in accepted answer, the workaround is to use the transactWriteItems method straight from the DynamoDB object.

Thanks for the help! =D
Cheers!

Comment: the feature has been introduced in release 2.365.0 Are you sure you are using latest sdk have you run npm install again with new dependencies in place ?

Comment: I tried to update it again today, in my packages.json the version is ^2.368 but I still get the same error.

Comment: can you try it with  initializing everything in a new directory and then run npm install

Comment: Did it with no success. Also, I tried to change the "action" param (the method name) on the DocumentClient call to TransactWriteItems, TransactWrite, transactWriteItems and transactWrite, also with no success.
Can you use the methods on your environment? Can you show me an example call so I can try to find my error, please?

Comment: If you can take a look at [document_client.d.js](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/v2.368.0/lib/dynamodb/document_client.js), you can see that there is no transact operator present on the map.

Comment: that's true let's have a discussion in chat room https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86481/varnit-chatroom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

The issue has been resolved

[Github Thread](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/2392)

AWS SDK is not currently supporting transactions in dynamodb document client i have raised the issue on github a current workaround is just not to use document client

```
let aws=require("aws-sdk");
aws.config.update(
    {
        region:"us-east-1",
        endpoint: "dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"    

    }
);
var dynamodb = new  aws.DynamoDB();


dynamodb.transactWriteItems();
```

Also make sure you are using SDK v2.365.0 plus

Answer (score 0):

Update the ***aws-sdk*** package (>2.365)

Use
`var dynamodb = new aws.DynamoDB();`

instead of
`var dynamodb = new aws.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();`